# Are HTML Forms for an AWS-SDK?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm new to [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp) and been working on creating a site with [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/). 
I've seen that [< form >](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)s are typical syntax for data requests.

Since I'm using the [AWS-SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/), I'm having a hard time making [< form >](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) fit the AWS-SDK format. Should I not be using < form > here? Otherwise, what am I not understanding?

```
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <!-- Stuff -->
        <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="assets/js/myscript.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body> class="container-fluid"> 
        <!-- Stuff -->
        <table class="container" style="text-align:center">
            <!-- Stuff -->
            <tr class="row row-eq-height">
               <td class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <input id="createItem" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="createItem();" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
        <!-- Stuff --> 
    </body>
</html>
```

```
// Stuff

var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

// Stuff

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

// Stuff
```

Comment: Well if you still use a `form` and the client disables `javascript` (disabling the ability to use ajax) your form will still run the default action of POST which will send the data to whatever file is set so it could be good as a fallback but not many people disable `javascript` I think this would cause the client more problems with page usability/functionality.

Comment: When do those cases happen though. I've yet to have clear examples, only abstracts.

Comment: He already said when they would happen: when the client disables Javascript in the browser.

Comment: This is not an appropriate place to rant about downvotes. Nobody is expected to disclose why they downvoted; votes are anonymous by design. The reason for downvoting is given by the tooltip on the downvote arrow. For help on your question ban, please see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). Note that, as it says there, deleting all your old questions is not the way to solve this problem. Nor is creating a new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the forms are bad for working with AWS-SDK. 
They add extra complexity in adhering to both standards without yielding either's benefits in clarity or simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* use semantic HTML elements. And yes, you should use the `form` element.

### Semantics and Accessibility

Spiders, User Agents, Screenreaders, Plugins etc. read your website and try to make sense of it. Browsers might help their users by prefilling saved contact data. Spiders might behave differently if the semantics are not clear. Should a spider click on a `button` element? Most bots of search engines do not click them if they are submit buttons `type="submit"` but they might otherwise as some websites (semantically incorrect) use buttons instead of links. Screenreaders can announce form blocks to their blind or visually impaired users. Password manager might prefill login forms only (and not every single input field that is on your website with `name="name"`). All of that is massively simplified with semantic `form`s. Without them, those features might not work well or completely break.

### JavaScript API and Data Validation

Semantic HTML and JavaScript can be used together. When you are using `form`s, you can properly reference it from JavaScript by using [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms). You can get its [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements), you can listen to its [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event), you can [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) it or do other things with it.

[Data validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) allows the browser to do the validation of values for you. JavaScript provides [`reportValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) to check whether a form is valid or you can use the [`invalid` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/invalid_event). Validating a whole form this way is much easier than doing it with JavaScript only (especially, when you don't use a form).

### Disabled JavaScript

Some people have JavaScript disabled. It is always good to make your website work in that case.

Comment: Why would I want to help spiders?
Won't that just help other people spam the sites or abuse features?

Comment: There is nothing from with spiders in general. Google uses spiders to crawl your website for instance.

Answer (score -2):

HTML forms are useful mainly for the formatting reasons. They look like the users expect them to look + there are plenty of CSS frameworks (Bootstrap, Material Design, ...) that provide beautiful out-of-the-box form elements with no effort.

It is however no longer needed to wrap the form into the `<form>` element as processing the data from the form is typically done by a Javascript function which would access directly the form elements.

Typically, you would place a `<button>` at the end of the form and put an onclick event on it that would be used to submit the form.

Comment: Than's Mikulas, this is so much more helpful in fewer words!